# Object.keys doesn't print the method name as a property

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, ecmascript-5

I am using protractor to select a table using the xpath `data-grid[@name="someTable"]` and then using the classname `someColumn` to select cells in a column.

```
var cells = element(by.xpath('//data-grid[@name="someTable"]').all(by.css('.someColumn'))
```

When i do `Object.keys(cells)` (or) `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cells)`, it doesn't show the `count` property.

`Object.keys` outputs,

```
ptor_,getWebElements,actionResults_,locator_,click,sendKeys,getTagName,getCssValue,getAttribute,getText,getSize,getLocation,isEnabled,isSelected,submit,clear,isDisplayed,getOuterHtml,getInnerHtml,getId,getRawId
```

When i do,

```
expect(numberOfRows.count()).toBe(2)
```

it works

Why doesn't the `count` function get displayed when printing the properties of the `cells` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `count()` in protractor is not a property of an `element`/`elements.all()`. `count()` function works on top of ElementArray and returns the value by counting the number of elements with the locator specified. [Check the implementation of count()](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2.2.0/lib/element.js#L333).

> Its just a wrapper over element locator which puts in all the located
>   elements into an array and then returns the array's length as count in
>   the form of promise.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `Object.keys()` method returns the *enumerable* properties of an object. Some properties may be present with the `enumerable` flag set to `false`. You can try

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(numberOfRows, "count"));
```

to see.

Comment: i already tried `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cells)` to get non-enumerables but of no use... i tried your fix as well, it returns undefined...

Comment: @MadhavanKumar my suggestion is not a "fix" - the issue is that not all properties of an object are enumerable.